# PHP gettext variations uppercase/lowercase

Tags: php, gettext

I have gettext setup and working on Windows and IIS. I have translated US English to GB English. All is working well but I have a question which searching could not answer.

Do I need to have multiple translations for each variation of a word (uppercase, lowercase)?

```
Colour -> Color
colour -> color
COLOUR -> COLOR
```

etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you do.  GETTEXT is case-sensitive.

Remember that different languages use different rules for capitalisation.

English "fish" is German "Fisch" (nouns are always capitalised).

Also remember that upper/lower case is a feature of latin scripts.  Languages written in hebrew, arabic, etc. do not have capitals, so if you are using capitals to indicate emphasis, etc., you should find an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am only using US and GB which is good...for now.

Comment: Depending on the languages used, you might get away with using lower case in your translation file, then wrap the translated text with `ucwords` or `strtoupper`.